# What is the correct way to be able to serve up an ASP.NET MVC page with URL /areas?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get ASP.MVC to handle the URL /areas i.e. http://example.com/areas. By convention there is a folder called Areas, so /areas never gets to my controller.

I want to be able to tell MVC to ignore this folder in this one case.

Ordinarily I would not use a name that conflicts with an existing folder but I am migrating a web application from Django to ASP.NET MVC and have a section of pages under /areas. I would prefer not to have to change all the existing URL's just because of the framework.

For performance reasons I would prefer not to configure all requests to go through the MVC pipeline.

What other solutions are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible to use the IIS URL Rewrite module to redirect requests to specific folder  and avoid the MVC pipeline completely.

The example below is from http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/ which shows how to rewrite paths to point at a static resource (Under the heading "Static content management.")

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to new folder">
            <match url="^Images/(.+)$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="NewImages/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious if you could use an IgnoreRoute in your global.asax.cs file which would cause MVC to ignore that completely and not use the MVC processor for anything in that folder

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("areas/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: The problem is that I do want to handle areas as a route, I just don't want IIS to not hit MVC because there is a folder that exists.